# Find feature Importance not on basis of count but importance

Tags: r, svm, random-forest

I am developing a model for company users where there are multiple independent features which contributes to dependent feature userValue.

I have generated 10k fake records programmatically and assigned 0/1 to each feature. 0 means feature is not valid for the user and 1 means it is.

Now code is as follows.

```
sv.user.data <- user.data[,-1:-2]
indexes <- sample(1:nrow(sv.user.data), size=0.95*nrow(sv.user.data))
train.data <- sv.user.data[indexes,]
test.data <- sv.user.data[-indexes,]

## separate feature and class variables
test.feature.vars <- test.data[,-26]
test.class.var <- test.data[,26]

formula.init <- "userValue ~ ."
formula.init <- as.formula(formula.init)

model <- train(formula.init, data=train.data, method = 'svmLinear', trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 2))

importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)
plot(importance, cex.lab=0.5)
```

Now when the plot is printing I see that highest importance is given to the feature which has maximum occurrence, whereas my requirement is to give highest importance to the feature which contributes maximum to the userValue which is dependent feature.

Suppose the feature A contributes 100 to the userValue and feature B contributes 10 to the userValue but somehow feature B has 10X occurence hence in the plot it is coming at maximum importance however I want feature to take precedence  as it is the most contributing crucial factor.

Comment: a) What do you mean with "feature which has maximum occurrence"? Do you refer to binary features? How do you measure maximum occurrence? b) What do do you mean with "feature A contributes 100 to the userValue [...]" in context of a linear SVM?

Comment: @geekoverdose a) By maximum occurrence I mean the feature which has value 1(numeric) for almost all users is coming up as most important feature in plot but say this feature contributes minimum to the userValue and say there is another feature will has only 5% occurrence for users with value 1 but contributes 10x then the former feature to the userValue. These features have value 0 or 1, 0 means the feature doesn't exists for users and doesnt contribute to userValue and 1 means the feature exists for the users and it contributes to the userValue.

Comment: @geekoverdose b) by this I mean that feature A being of value 1 contributes numeric 100 to the userValue and feature B if it has value 1, then it contributes 10 to userValue. Basically I have allocates weight to each of feature and if any of them has value 1 for user, there is a add up to the userValue based on weight/importance of each feature.  As I mentioned feature A adds 100 to userValue and feature B adds 10 to userValue. Like this I have 26 features and each contribute to userValue score based on individual weight associated with each of them.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=46233500475259322811

Comment: @geekoverdose let me if you can download the file from here

Comment: What do you mean by "contributes most to the dependent varaible"?

Comment: @MatthewDrury I mean contributes a higher integer/value to the dependent variable userValue.

Comment: Can you unwind that more, what does 'contributes' mean?

Comment: @MatthewDrury suppose there are three independent feature a,b and c. X is dependent feature which depends on value of a,b and c. Now I have assumed 'a' is least important feature, 'b' is medium important and 'c' is critical. So they contribute to value of x such as x <- a + 2b + 3c. a,b and c I am representing as 0 or 1 depending upon if they are applicable for a particular user. if all 3 features are present of user then x <- 1+ 2*1+ 3*1 => X <- 6 . Like this I have 26 different features.

Answer (score 0):

*I didn't think this through in full detail, so just point out if anything seems a bit weird.*

Your target variable is a weighted combination of (binary) features, which still essentially is a linear combination of features. The best model for such would be a linear model/generalized linear model (LM), which, given some data, will model this relation pretty well using an appropriate slope and intercept. A support vector machine instead models its regression fit ("tube") using support vectors only, so essentially those samples ending up close to/in the margin. From my understanding, you might be better off using a LM in this case instead (this is the part I didn't think through fully because I lack the imagination of the details of the SVM regression loss function is this setup).

One further thing:

```
sort(cor(train.data[,-(1:2)])[,24], decreasing = T)

                     userWeight 
                      1.0000000 
              Employee_Portal_2 
                      0.7135050 
      Excelity_Payroll_System_2 
                      0.5450896 
   Financial_Management_Suite_2 
                      0.4945498 
                         HRMS_1 
                      0.3365252 
                         HRMS_2 
                      0.2991008
                          [...]
```

yields a pretty similar order to `varImp` on the SVM model:

[image: varImp plot]

For SVM models, `varImp` states:

> For SVM classification models, the default behaviour is to compute the area under the ROC curve.

So, your SVM variable importance will emphasize those variables that have strongly discriminative power on their own *by design*. In contrast, for linear models, `varImp` states:

> Linear Models: the absolute value of the t--statistic for each model parameter is used.

```
model2 <- train(x = train.data[,-26], y = train.data[,26], method = 'glm', trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 10))
plot(varImp(model2, scale=F), cex.lab = 0.5)
```

[image: varImp plot2]

Does this look more like what you would expect?

Comment: What is a variable importance statistic from a GLM?

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thx, I added what `varImp` computes with linear models in the answer.

Comment: @geekoverdose this looks better..but still I was expecting feature like F_M_Suite_1 to come on top as it contributes maximum to the userValue

Comment: @geekoverdose so you think higher occurrence of low importance features are responsible for such outcome ?